# The impediment generates that in relation to which it is an impediment . <-- analysis?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses, noun-phrases

Can someone help me analyze the grammar of the following sentence?

> In a paradoxical logic, the impediment generates that in relation to which it is an impediment.

I'm very confused by "that in relation to which it".

Answer (score 1):

> In a paradoxical logic, the impediment generates that in relation to which it is an impediment.

The biggest problem with this sentence is the word *that*, which a reader is likely to initially understand as the beginning of a relative clause or a subordinate content clause. In actual fact, the word *that* here is a noun phrase (strictly speaking, a determinative) meaning *that thing*, just like when we say *Give me that!* or *That which doesn't kill us makes us stronger*.

The word  *that* **is** followed by a relative clause, but the relative clause, confusingly, does not start with the word *which*! The relative word *which* is technically the object of a preposition *to*, and this preposition *to* is embedded in the preposition phrase *in relation to*. The writer has taken this whole long preposition phrase from the end of the sentence and moved it round to the beginning of the relative clause, right after the word *that* (this is called *pied-piping* in the trade). This was optional, the writer could have left the preposition phrase at the end. The relative clause thus begins with the phrase *in relation to which*.

If you look below, you can see roughly how the relative clause was constructed, and where the word *that*, meaning *that thing* fits in. As you will see, many bits of this sentence have been moved away from their normal positions while making the relative clause.

- An impediment is an impediment in relation to a thing, X <sup>[presumably it hinders X]</sup>
- The impediment  generates **the thing** which it is an impediment in relation to <s>the thing</s>.
- The impediment generates the thing **in relation to** which it is an impediment <s>in relation to</s>.
- The impediment generates  <s>the</s> **that** thing in relation to which it is an impediment.
- The impediment generates **that** <s>thing</s> in relation to which it is an impediment.
- The impediment generates that in relation to which it is an impediment.

Roughly speaking, the sentence could be paraphrased like this:

> In a paradoxical logic, an impediment generates the very thing it impedes.

Comment: I think I agree with you! To be clear, "that" is a demonstrative determinative. It's independent here, and thus functioning as a fused determiner-head in NP structure.

Comment: What does *it* refer to in those constructions?

Comment: @TinfoilHat The word *it* in those examples (and the example in the question) refers to "the impediment". A bit awkward and clankerty, but it means "the impediment generates the thing  in relation to which the impediment is an impediment"

Comment: @BillJ — Are saying that *that* is a fused determiner-head in *The impediment generates that which it is an impediment to*?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, it is. So, I assume that's what BiilJ's saying.

Comment: I am trying to determine if *CGEL* really considers the demonstrative pronoun *that*, as used in *...that which...* to also be a fused head.

Comment: @TinfoilHat It's *never* a pronoun according to CGEL.

Comment: I see that now. I also see that *today* is a pronoun therein. Whee.

Comment: @TinfoilHat What would you classify *today* as?